# Nest MultiMatchQuery doesn't return result

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to make a query which finds a presence of the word in different fields of the object `MyType` (all 11 fields `int` and `string`). In *Postman* the query below gives a result.

Query by *Postman*:

```
http://esserver.com/_search
{
   "query": {
      "multi_match" : {
         "query":    "word", 
         "fields": [ "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5", "field6", 
            "field7", "field8", "field9", "field10", "field11" ] 
       }
    }
}
```

The query below doesn't return anything, but if I search within 3 fields of `MyType` everything works properly and I receive a result.

```
public List<MyType> SearchByText(String str, string[] search_fields)
{    
    List<PropertyPathMarker> ppm_List = new List<PropertyPathMarker>();
    search_fields.ToList().ForEach(fld => ppm_List.Add(fld));
    MultiMatchQuery query = new MultiMatchQuery { Fields = ppm_List, Query = str };
    // method below doesn't return any results
    var result = es_client.Search<object>(s => s.Query(query)).Hits;
    ... 
}
```

Am I wrong? If yes, where is the mistake?

**Update 1:**

ElasticSearch version 5.4.1, NEST version 1.5.1

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting? Can you edit your question and add those?

Comment: @RussCam, added es and nest vesrion

Comment: That version of NEST is not compatible with Elasticsearch 5.4.1. You should update to the latest NEST 5.x version (5.5.0 at time of writing: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/5.5.0)

Comment: @RussCam I have legacy code and need to add just one query. Is it possible to search by MultiMatchQuery with NEST 1.5.1?

Comment: Yes (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/1.5.1/src/Nest/DSL/Query/MultiMatchQueryDescriptor.cs) **but no guarantee it will work against Elasticsearch 5.4.1**